# is it possible to regenerate pagination after ajax update?

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to regenerate pagnation after I have made ajax call that changes number of pages that would be returned?

this is how I call it in the blade right now

```
$comments->links()
```

Then I allow user to appove/unapprove/mark as spam etc using ajax and after I made ajax call I would like to regenerate pagination without having to reload the page, has anyone done it and how?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should have done your pagination in first place in js, something line vue.js makes it easy to work with:

http://www.vuescript.com/pagination/

Comment: I am not using Vue in my project, however I have figured it out, put pagination in a separate blade file and render that file and return it in ajax response, problem solved :)